# How to remove HTML code with jquery that is not inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code on my page that I dont have access to and need to remove it. Unfortunately it doesnt sit within a specific div.

```html
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
* html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
@media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
* html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
}
</style>
```

How could I remove this with a jquery code?

I would really appreciate any help!!

Comment: Do you want to remove the whole style tag?

Comment: You mean the whole media=screen? Yes! My page has content and many other styles, but non refering to media=screen apart from the above code that I'm trying to remove.

Comment: How do you have access to javascript/jquery to the page and not the page itself?

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick

```
$('style[media="screen"]').remove()
```

if you want it on page load then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('style[media="screen"]').remove()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how specific the tag is, you can potentially try targeting it with selectors to find it

```
var badStyles = $('style[type*="text/css"]');
```

From here you likely want to determine if it is the correct element as you may have several style elements:

```
var badStyles = $('style[type*="text/css"]');
badStyles.each(function(i) {
    if($(this).html().indexOf('html { margin-top: 32px !important; }')> 0){
        $(this).empty();  
    }
});
```

.empty() will remove the contents, however .remove() will remove the entire tag if you so wish.

To demonstrate in practice:

https://jsfiddle.net/z3g1Le1k/

Comment: I've revised this to now properly only delete the specified style.

Comment: Pleas try my solution again, I have fixed it since you downvoted me.